# JSONに配列をセットする場合の記述が分からない

Tags: python, json

現在、Pythonの勉強をしており、APIを利用したプログラムを作成しています。
が、パラーメータにセットする値に配列を利用したいのですが、うまくいきません。
どのように記述すればよろしいでしょうか。

わかりづらい点もあるかと思いますが、ご教授いただけないでしょうか…

```js
json_data = {
    'destination': {
        'XXX': XX,
    },
    'source': {
        'ipRanges': [
            "11111",      // ★ここを配列にしたい
            "22222"　　　　// ★ここを配列にしたい
          ]
    }
}
```

Comment: 「うまくいかない」とありますが、既に試した内容を質問に追記してみてください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
このようにしたいのですが、
code: SEM0002, message: Error occurred: Internal Server Error
上記エラーが返却され、うまくいかない状態です…
json_data = {
    'destination': {
        'XXX': XX,
    },
    'source': {
        'ipRanges': [
　　　　　ip_ranges['value'],
          ]
    }
}

Comment: 質問に貼られたものはそもそも JSON としては正しくないです。何なのですかそれは？

Answer (score 0):

以下のように単純に配列の入れ子にすれば良いと思われます。
JSONとしてはこれで有効なデータとなるはずです。

```
{
    "destination": {
        "XXX": 0
    },
    "source": {
        "ipRanges": [
            [
                "11111",
                "22222"
            ],
            [
                "33333",
                "44444"
            ]
          ]
    }
}
```

例えばこんなサイトでオンラインでチェックできます。
[JSON Validator](https://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidator)

---

実は送るデータの形式だけでは無く、受け取って処理する側の対処も必要だが、それをまだやっていないとかでは？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
このようにしたいのですが、
code: SEM0002, message: Error occurred: Internal Server Error
上記エラーが返却され、うまくいかない状態です…
json_data = {
    'destination': {
        'XXX': XX,
    },
    'source': {
        'ipRanges': [
　　　　　ip_ranges['value'],
          ]
    }
}

Comment: それは何か別の現象や問題では無いですか？ 新規に別の質問を立てた方が良いでしょう。[Amazon SageMaker で InternalServerError レスポンスのトラブルシューティングを行うにはどうすればよいですか？](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sagemaker-http-500-internal-server-error/), [Amazon S3 からのHTTP500または503エラーのトラブルシューティングを行うにはどうすればよいですか？](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/http-5xx-errors-s3/), [HTTP API Lambda 統合に関する問題のトラブルシューティング](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-troubleshooting-lambda.html)